# Laravel 5.5 - Blade templates, querying deeper into a hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-blade

I am wondering if I can query a hasOne -> hasMany relationship in blade. I can currently get a count on how many models exist in my blade using "$participant->messages->count()" but I would like to check the model and count other things. For instance I would like to run the following query in blade:

```
{!! $participant->messages->where($this->messages->mediaURL, "=", null)->count() !!}
```

I get the following error:

```
Property [mediaURL] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function showParticipants()
{
    $participants = Participant::all();
  //  $messages = $participants->participant_id->messages;

    return view('home')->with(['participants'=> $participants, 'messages'=>'hi']);
}
```

Part of my Participant model:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'message_id', 'participant_id');
}
```

Part of my Message model:

```
public function participant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Participant::class);
}
```

My message table structure:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('message_content')->nullable();
        $table->string('mediaSID')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('messageSID')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('mediaURL')->index()->nullable();
        $table->binary('media')->nullable();
        $table->string('filename')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('MIMEType')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('messages', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('message_id')->references('participant_id')->on('participants')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

My Participant DB structure:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->string('participant_id')->unique();
        $table->dateTime('appointmentDate')->nullable();
        $table->dateTimeTz('timezoneOffset')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('appointmentDate_twoWeeks')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('notificationTime')->nullable();
        $table->integer('notificationTally')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('studyCompleted')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('subscribed');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My blade just to give all info:

```
                @isset($participants)
                  @foreach ($participants as $participant)
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->participant_id !!}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->subscribed !!}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->notificationTime !!}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->notificationTally !!}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->studyCompleted !!}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->messages->count() !!}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {!! $participant->messages->where($participant->messages->mediaURL, "=", null)->count() !!}
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                @endisset
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is `$this->messages->mediaURL`. With the Query Builder, if you're wanting to refer to a column on a table you would just need to pass it a string. Also when you're querying a relationship you should use the method and not the property e.g. `$participant->messages()`. Lastly, when querying for a null column you can use the `whereNull` method.

```
{!! $participant->messages()->whereNull('mediaURL')->count() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "magic" __get() on messages that returns a collection because it is a has many relationship.

```
$participant->messages->where($this->messages->mediaURL, "=", null)->count()
```

should be

```
 $participant->messages()->where($participant->messages()->first()->mediaURL, "=", null)->count()
```